# How to purge a Azure ServiceBus Topics Subscrption in C# (Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus v3+)?

Tags: c#, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

How can I (in C#) purge an Azure service bus's topic subscription using the Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus package (version 3+)?

I am aware of SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46922689/how-to-purge-messages-for-service-bus-topic-subscription?rq=1).  But the selected answer seems to use ReceiveBatch() on SubscriptionClient which does not appear to be available anymore(?).  SubscriptionClient only really seems to now have RegisterMessageHandler() to handle messages, however using this means my client would never know when the subsciption is actually empty.

Is there a clean way to purge a topic using C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `MessageReceiver` class in similar manner:

```
IMessageReceiver messageReceiver = new MessageReceiver(
    namespaceConnectionString,
    EntityNameHelper.FormatSubscriptionPath(topicName, subscriptionName),
    ReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete);

int batchSize = 100;
var operationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);

do
{
    var messages = await messageReceiver.ReceiveAsync(batchSize, operationTimeout);
    if (messages == null || messages.Count == 0) // Returns null if no message is found
    {
       break;
    }
}
while (true);
```

Note that only async API is now available.

Comment: ReceiveAsync often keeps returning null for me.  Are you aware of any reasons it might do this?

Comment: @nashwan Docs say "Returns null if no message is found", so yes, I updated my answer

Comment: yeah thought so :-). Also you can use .Count as IList is returned from ReceiveAsync. In my code I also added operationTimeout of a few seconds when calling ReceiveAsync otherwise I can be waiting quite a while for it to finish.

Comment: @nashwan Great! Feel free to edit my answer with your final code.

Comment: done.  IMO you can also just use a while(true) no need for do/while... but then thats just a matter of taste I guess :-)

Comment: Thanks. True, I copied do-while from the original answer.

Comment: As a side note, you may also close the `MessageReceiver`